# Changing Latex section numbering presentation

Tags: latex, formatting, document, roman-numerals

I'm trying to change how section numbering is displayed in a Latex document I'm working on. What I want to do is this:

**Section Title**
    (i) Subsection title in normal weight
        (a) Lorem ipsum (no subsubsection title being used)...

I've come up with the following, but it's not right in terms of indenting etc.

`\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{(\textnormal{\roman{subsection}})}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\indent(\textnormal{\alph{subsubsection}})}`

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `titlesec` package. [The `titlesec` manual is here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf), and plenty of other resources are available elsewhere.

Comment: The link is now dead it seems.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer, but the [memoir package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) provides some help with customization and is very well documented.