# LaTeX Change Default Section format

Tags: latex

The following code demonstrates the default `\section` heading along with a custom `\tcolorbox`.  I would like to alter the `\section` default to utilize the custom `\tcolorbox` function.

**How can I change the default `\section` format to the customized `\tcolorbox`?**

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage[margin=.5in, top=.5in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\raggedright\raggedbottom

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{SectionEnv}{
    enhanced,
    sharp corners=uphill,
    colback=gray!50,
    colframe=black,
    coltext=black,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=1mm,
    boxsep=1mm
}
\begin{document}

\section{Default Section Heading} % <-- default section heading

\begin{SectionEnv}

    \textbf{Desired Section Heading}

\end{SectionEnv}

\end{document}
```

Output of current code:

[image: Output from LaTeX]

I reviewed this post on [Changing Latex section numbering presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737255/changing-latex-section-numbering-presentation) however was unable to make use of the posted response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33217

```
\documentclass[letter,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\RequirePackage[margin=.5in, top=.5in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\raggedright\raggedbottom

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\section}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\sectionbox}{}{\PatchFailed}

\newcommand*{\sectionbox}[1]{%
\begin{tcolorbox}
                 [
    enhanced,
    sharp corners=uphill,
    colback=gray!50,
    colframe=black,
    coltext=black,
    arc=3mm,
    boxrule=1mm,
    boxsep=1mm
                 ]
  #1
\end{tcolorbox} 
} %


\begin{document}

\section{Default Section Heading} % <-- default section heading



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  And with minor modification of `\section*{Default Section Heading}` I was able to remove the auto numbering.